# Title is not working in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set title attribute

using **ng-attr-title** and i am using this code

```
<a href="" ng-attr-title="Delete">dddd</a>
```

and here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vot70qya/

and this is not working

Comment: just `title="Delete"` ?

Comment: i dnt want to use only title

Comment: @RoyDictus: it's not working and my title says.  i need ng-attr-title to work

Comment: Hey can you tell us why ng-attr-title not title simple ?

Comment: i need some condition behind this..

Comment: <a ng-attr-title="{{Delete}}" href="">Delete</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution

```
<a href="" ng-attr-title="{{'Delete'}}">dddd</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either do like what you have done before, or have a scope variable so that you can apply conditions in your controller and then appropriately use the scope variable here

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/suft5oNCdUUvQ6PsGNLc?p=preview)

Controller Code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.delete = 'delete';
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <a href="" ng-attr-title="{{delete}}">dddd</a>
</body>
```